# PUBLICTOKEN = JO1VLV2G4K2O7QJTI99ONANEFR IS INVALID in blazemeter

Tags: blazemeter

Recording through blazemeter and tryinng to export to jmeter and I am getting the following exception:

> PUBLICTOKEN = JO1VLV2G4K2O7QJTI99ONANEFR IS INVALID

What should be the problem?

Comment: I take it you mean Chrome Blazemeter plugin when exporting to .jmx format - I got the same error. Work-around - Select "Edit" option instead and then select .jmx export from there.

Comment: That work-around worked once for me - now also failing - I have flagged to Blazemeter support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all.

Actually you need to login to blaze meter. I tried after logged in and it exported successfully. You can find the login or signup option at the top right corner of chrome blaze meter extension.

Comment: I was logged in when I got the problem - but (as elsewhere on this thread) the problem seemed intermittent.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround of opening in edit and then exporting from there didn't work for me too.

Instead I opened for edit and left that window opened. Then clicked on the Chrome blazemeter plug-in again and clicked 'export to jmeter' from the plug-in. This is working multiple times for me.

Comment: The problem appears intermittent - working for me now - for reference I have raised a ticket #109041 with Blazemeter support.

Answer (score 0):

Another work-around (as indicated by Blazemeter support) is to :

Edit > Save as Json - then use http://converter.blazemeter.com to get .jmx file